# One Column combination with all other columns using pandas

Tags: pandas, cartesian-product

I will really appreciate any help here. My data frame is in this format

x1  x2  x3 ;

1   101 201;

2   102 202

I want to get in this in this format

x1  x2  x3 ;

1   101 201 ;

1   102 202 ;

2   101 201 ;

2   102 202

I can use cartesian product which gives all combination. Thanks for your help.

`list(itertools.product(tx['x1'],tx['x2'],tx['x3']))`

I am learning pandas, just stuck.

[Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5zah.png)

Comment: I dont think the expected output that you pasted is the result of `cartesian product`.

Answer (score 1):

Cartesian Product will give you below and not what you pasted:

```
1   101   201 
1   101   201 
2   102   202 
2   102   202
```

You can achieve this by adding a dummy column to your df like:

```
d1['key'] = 1
In [710]: d1
Out[710]: 
   x1   x2   x3  key
0   1  101  201    1
1   2  102  202    1
```

Then, join `d1` with itself on `key` for a cartesian product:

```
In [819]: pd.merge(d1,d1,on='key')[['x1_x','x2_x','x3_x']]
Out[819]: 
   x1_x  x2_x  x3_x
0     1   101   201
1     1   101   201
2     2   102   202
3     2   102   202
```

Let me know if this is what you want?